# Tabs inside fragment without creating additional fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create a fragment as a part of a much bigger app. This fragment has to be called from a MainActivity. The fragment itself must contain some tabs. However, I don't want to make new fragment classes for each tab. Just loading an XML file would do. Is is possible?

Most tutorials I found online have a fragment for each tab.

Comment: You could have one simple Fragment class that takes a parameter in the constructor that tells it which xml layout to inflate.

Comment: Yeah but it would be difficult to implement tabs right? I was thinking of a base fragment to implement tabs. place another fragment using the approach you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it as views by pager adapter check this http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/